# Linq to Nhibernate - Compare 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq-to-nhibernate, linq-expressions, intersect

I have 2 lists and I need to know if there are any matches.  I've tried using `request.Interests.Intersect(x.Post.Tags.Split(' ')).Count() > 0` but I get the error

> System.NotImplementedException : The
>   method Intersect is not implemented.

So, I tried a recursive function that returns a bool.  And it's as if the function call is just ignored.

Here's my function

```
private bool GenerateInterestsExpression(string postTags, string[] interests)
        {
            if (interests.Length == 0)
                return false;

            string interest = interests[0];

            var newInterests = interests.ToList();
            newInterests.Remove(interest);

            return GenerateInterestsExpression(postTags, newInterests.ToArray()) || postTags.ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf(interest.ToLowerInvariant()) >= 0;
        }
```

here's what the relevant piece of my linq expression looks like.

```
request.Profile.Tags.Count == request.Interests.Length

                                        ||

                                        (
                                            request.Profile.Tags.Count != request.Interests.Length

                                            &&

                                            x.Post.Tags != String.Empty

                                            &&

                                            (
                                                GenerateInterestsExpression(x.Post.Tags, request.Interests)
                                                                                           )
                                        )
```

When GenerateInteresExpression has a breakpoint in it, it does not pause.  I tried building a recursive function to build the expression on the fly, but I can't figure out how to chain the linq expressions together.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this with dynamic linq for linq to nhibernate?

Comment: i really want intersect support too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change it to use HQL and dynamically build the HQL query.

Comment: do you have any examples where you have it working with HQL as i have a similar request . .